# ¿Como inserto datos tipo date desde netbeans a sql?

Tags: java, sql, date, variables

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación para registrar facturas conectado a sql, pero mi problema es que no se como ingresar las fechas desde netbeans, trate con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se que hay otra forma que es con setString, pero a mi me gustaría guardarlo en una variable, así que me gustaría saber como puedo hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que estas usando `JDateChooser` que devuelve un objeto de tipo `Date`, entonces si quieres almacenar en una variable de tipo String lo que tienes que hacer es convertir a String, para el ejemplo formateando a dd/MM/YYYY.

```
public String fechaDate(Date d){
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
    return formatoFecha.format(d);
}

//Llamamos desde otro método

public void btnIngresarActionPerformed(){
    String fec = fechaDate(jDateChooser.getDate()); 
}
```

Comment: Lo implemente y me dio la siguiente excepción: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Olvídalo, lo solucione, solo lo había puesto al reves XD